# VueJS adding active class to a sidebar link

Tags: vue.js

I have a VueJS project which is an admin panel. It has 4 different main components, Header, Footer, Container and Sidebar. I want my Sidebar links to be highlighted when I click on them. Let's say I clicked the Administration link from my sidebar. I want its background color to be something different. I managed to do that but when I click somewhere else in the page, the highligted color is gone. I want the link highlighted unless I click another sidebar link. How do I do that?

Here is my sidebar template;

```
<template>
 <!-- Sidebar Start -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar User Panel -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img
            src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg"
            class="img-circle elevation-2"
            alt="User Image"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block">Product Name</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar Menu Start -->
      <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <router-link tag="li" to="/dashboard" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="dashboard_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">dashboard</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Dashboard</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/cloudconnect" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="cloudconnect_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">cloud_queue</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Cloud Connect</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/activeclients" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="activeclients_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">devices</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Active Clients</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/internetaccess" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="internetaccess_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">public</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Internet Access</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/wifisettings" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="wifisettings_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">wifi</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Wi-Fi Settings</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/lansettings" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="lansettings_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">account_tree</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">LAN Settings</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/guestaccess" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="guestaccess_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">people_alt</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Guest Access</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/vpnconnect" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="vpnconnect_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">vpn_lock</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">VPN Connect</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/poemanagement" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="poemanagement_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">flash_on</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">PoE Management</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/forwarding" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="forwarding_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">settings_ethernet</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Forwarding</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/security" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="security_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">security</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Security</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/softwareupdate" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="softwareupdate_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">system_update_alt</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Software Update</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/systemsettings" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="systemsettings_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">settings</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">System Settings</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
          <router-link tag="li" to="/diagnostics" class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a class="nav-link" id="diagnostics_tab">
              <i class="sidebar-icons">shuffle</i>
              <p class="sidebar-links">Diagnostics</p>
            </a>
          </router-link>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- Sidebar Menu End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Sidebar End -->
  </aside>
</template>
```

When I click a route link, the background of that specific link becomes orange and I want it to stay orange till I click another sidebar link. But when I click somewhere else in the project, the orange background is gone.

Comment: which css framework are you using?

Comment: I dont use any framework for my CSS files

Answer (score 0):

You need to define router-active-link class to style active link element. You can either define it to your global css or under your style tag inside of your component. For example:

```css
.router-link-active {

  background-color: #000;
  padding: 2rem;

}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this one and let you know!

Comment: Were you able to try? I appreciate if you accep my answer, if it worked for you. :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

> Style

```
.activeClass {
      /* background-color: var(--v-primary-base) !important; */
      background: linear-gradient(98deg,#000000,var(--v-primary-base) 94%);
      color: var(--v-primary-lighten1) !important;
    }
```

> Your router link

```
    <router-link tag="li" to="/forwarding" active-class="activeClass" exact class="nav-item has-treeview">
     <a class="nav-link" id="forwarding_tab">
       <i class="sidebar-icons">settings_ethernet</i>
       <p class="sidebar-links">Forwarding</p>
     </a>
   </router-link>
```